# Which file is System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings using?

Tags: .net, configuration-files

I want to know which *.config file the ConfigurationManager is using.  How can I figure that out?

For instance, you could be changing working directories and execute libraries from various paths.  I'd love to have a way to display something like "Reading AppSettings from c:\MyApp\app.config" in my Trace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath
```

Comment: Doesn't work when running in a web app.  "exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe."

Comment: When running a web app you need to use     System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").FilePath;